# Robot framework expected error failed: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a problem with Robot Framework.

Currently I do negative testing. I have a JSON response with length of an array `5` data (counting from 0). I want to check if the `6`th exists or not. If the `6`th data does not exist, the test is passed.

Here's my code:

```
${msg}    Run Keyword And Expect Error    Resolving variable '${json_response['data'][5]}' failed: IndexError: list index out of range    *    Log To Console    ${json_response['data'][5]}
Should Contain    ${msg}    failed: IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code gives failing results.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Please provide a sample of the variable's value, and what is the actual result of the `Log To Console` call.

Answer (score 0):

Better one would be to verify if list length is expecte one:

```
    ${json_length}    Get Length    ${json_response['data']}
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${json_length}    6
```